# How do I end a romantic relationship with the butler?

Tags: the-sims-3

Just to have some fun, I built up a romantic relationship between a sim and her butler. For a while it was amusing to see him get excited about the occasional WooHoo in the shower, but it has pretty much run its course.
Now that I'd like to end the relationship, I noticed that the "Mean" interactions menu is not available, so I can't ask him to "just be friends".
How do I break off this relationship so that my sim can pursue other romantic interests *without getting a naughty or cheater reputation*?

[image: Screenshot of butler dilemma]

Comment: KILL HIM!!! Bwahahahahahaha

Comment: @Michel I believe that when your romantic interest dies, you need to atone with their ghost before pursuing other romantic relationships, if you wish to not get the cheater reputation.

Comment: @DanRasmussen Still standing with my idea... =P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After thinking a bit more about it, I decided to try the following:

Dismiss the butler, wait until he/she has left the premises, then call him/her to invite him/her over.
He/she should then visit in everyday clothes. Since the butler is now off-duty, regular conversation options are available. "Ask To Just Be Friends" should therefore be listed in the Mean interactions menu.

After doing this you may want to hire another butler.

[image: Ask To Just Be Friends]

Comment: Good job finding the loophole!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it nicely, I believe the Sims must have a high enough relationship bar and be friendly to each other until the option appears to "Just be friends".

That means you shouldn't be doing any romantic actions anymore. I think the option appears soon enough and you won't get any negative points anymore.

That or let him swim, build a wall around it and drown the fellah! He had it coming!

Comment: I think the option is simply not available because he is a butler. I just realized how to solve this; see [my answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/107440/5581).